# How can I run multiple programming languages in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook with two cells.
In the first cell I have some Python 3 code.
In the second cell I have C# code.

I can pull-down the Kernel menu and change the kernel for the Python cell and it runs ok.
Likewise, I can change the kernel in the second cell to C# and it runs ok.

My question is: "How can I change the kernel in each cell programmatically?

Charles

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean magic commands?

https://ewinnington.github.io/posts/jupyter-tips-csharp

Try putting `%%csharp` on the first line:

```
%%csharp
// some c# code
```

This must be on the first line. Don't make the mistake of putting a comment on the first line and magic on the second line - this doesn't function.

Comment: I  tried "%%csharp" as the only line in a cell and I got "UsageError: Cell magic `%%csharp` not found."

Comment: I then ran "%lsmagic" in the next cell and I got a list of "Available line magics".  
csharp was not in this list.  How do I fix this?

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html says _To Jupyter users: Magics are specific to and provided by the IPython kernel. Whether Magics are available on a kernel is a decision that is made by the kernel developer on a per-kernel basis._ So what kernel are you using?